# Texture Distortions

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a strange problem with a self-created texture.
The output image is a * .jpg 330x890 pixels. In the 3D view "Material"
everything still looks like it should, but the material preview already shows
distortions. After rendering with the Blender engine (F12)
come out very strange geometric figures. Whats going on here?

[image]

Comment: There are many ways in which you can map a texture on to an object. You need to learn about **texture coordinates**. Watch this: https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=265

Answer (score 0):

sorry, that was my own mistake. I have changed the value of "distortion" in 3D-View, "properties" panel, "influence". Problem solved.